# File transfer activity to transfer file to custom FTP folder

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, ftp

In the FTP of marketing cloud we have three folders Import ,Export and Triggered automation . Just wondering if it is possible to create new folders in FTP and transfer file to those folders through file transfer activity .Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, however you will need to create a new File Location (Under Setup > Data Management > File Locations), pointing to "Triggered automation" folder:

[image]

Once you've done so, you can select it in step 2 of File Transfer Activity configuration:
[image]

Comment: Hi @Lukas, can you please tell me how do you create a new file location? I can't seem to find that option anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: See my updated answer @Duicug

Comment: Does this create a new folder in enhanced FTP or is it just relative path . I tried doing it but it doesnt seem to create a new directory . Is it so that new directory is not created.

Comment: @SandeepThapa - You need to create the directory on the FTP server, before you can use it in a File Location. This needs to be done using an  FTP client

Comment: @LukasLunow I tried to create a folder using FIleZilla and I have admin privilage but couldnt create it. Is there any specific roles you need to create directories in FTp .Thank you

Comment: @SandeepThapa - I admit there can be some inconsistent behaviour. I can't create folders in root on stack 4, but it is possible on e.g. stack 50. You can always create subfolders in /Export or /Import if needed

Comment: Thank you for the info . I was able to create inside ,that will work .